# Blocking programs from reading outside their allocated RAM

Tags: memory, security

I was wondering if I could keep program A from reading my entire ram, as it does not need to monitor what program B is doing.

Also I am on windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: Unless the program is specifically built to be able to inject itself in another processes memory space (i.e. using specific Windows programming calls that need administrative access), a program cannot see another programs memory. In other words, Notepad can't just "see" what's in the RAM for Internet Explorer (and vice versa). That being said, there is the notion of [sandboxing/jailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) applications that disallows them access to areas. Might that be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Programs running in Windows are unable to directly address RAM. They access virtual addresses. To access RAM you would need the aid of a kernel mode driver written for the purpose. (This is how some of Mark Russinovich's "sysinternals tools" do it: They install a driver that comes packaged as a resource within the .exe.)

As far as one program accessing another is concerned, every process in Windows already has its own virtual address space, separate and disjoint from all others. i.e. one program's 0x10000 is completely different from any other's 0x10000. No matter what address you try to look at, you're always looking at your own process's instance of that address.

**However:** The ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory APIs do allow programs to do  cross-process access (in terms of virtual addresses). To use them the process doing the "accessing" has to open another process with the PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_VM_WRITE rights granted. Processes running within your user session do normally have the ability to do this to each other (that is, the security descriptor on most processes does allow this for the creator of the process... which is you).

However, one program would have no way of knowing where anything of interest would be in another process. It would be a long, weary search for anything interesting. The vast majority of the attempts would result in an "address not defined" area, especially on a 64-bit system, most especially in Windows 8.1 and later. Even within the defined areas of virtual memory, it's not as though programs routinely tag their memory areas with context information, like "bank account number is here:" followed immediately by said account number.

It may be thought of as somewhat cavalier that any of your processes can access the "memory" (loosely interpreted) of any other. But remember, everything you do under one login ID and authorization is all considered to be done on the part of a single user. i.e. it's all your data anyway.

Frankly I would worry more about data on your disk. All files containing your data were created by you under your security ID, so any program running under your security ID can access them all. Worse, Windows default is to create all files with Read access granted to the "Users" group - essentially everyone. So programs running under other security IDs can read them too. And since files are often nicely named and put in nicely named and organized directories, finding "interesting" files like accounts.txt isn't that tough. NTFS file encryption won't help against a snooper program that's running under your own account. This is a far, far greater exposure than cross-process memory access.